# Convert Python list to string with new lines between each element

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, join

So I have a list

```
myList = ['apples \n', 'banana \n', 'orange \n']
```

I am then joining the list together

```
x = ''
x = x.join(myList)
```

and hoping that x now equals a multiline list for readability like

```
apples
banana
orange
```

but in reality when I call x without using Print(), I get `apples \n banana \n orange \n`

The reason why I want the multine option is my list elements actually are paragraphs and not simple words but I didn't want to clog up this demo.

How can I store a string variable with new lines included?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you `print(x)`, you will see the new lines in the string. When evaluating the result of an expression in the REPL, Python will put `\n` in place of the line breaks.

In the interactive interpreter, this can be seen with:

```
>>> myList = ['apples \n', 'banana \n', 'orange \n']
>>> x = ''
>>> x = x.join(myList)
>>> x
'apples \nbanana \norange \n'
>>> print(x)
apples 
banana 
orange
```

The line breaks are there, but just seeing the result of the expression `x` is different than actually printing the value, which causes the `\n` to be interpreted by your terminal.

Comment: Thanks, Right I understand this. To clarify again in the OP, I am trying not to use print. I am passing the variable 'x' into another package which can only accept a single string as the variable. The output is recieved in an email and not the interactive interpreter.

Comment: So the line breaks are definitely still there, it's just a matter of formatting. `\n` is a new line character, it's just a matter of how it's displayed. If your function takes a string, and it is looking for line breaks, `\n` will be a line break. `\n` is ASCII `0x0A`, which is a new line character.